# How to use operator and && for show "something"

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I have code to display "Hello World" based on size attributes.

The code is :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content','show_something', 5 );
function show_something() {
  if (is_tax('pa_size')) {
    echo "<h2>Hello World</h2>";
    }
}
```

The code above it's worked.

But what i want actually is add an additional one condition that is a color attribute that has a red value/term in addition to size attributes for displaying "Hello World"

What I have tried is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content','show_something', 5 );
function show_something() {
  if (is_tax('pa_size') && is_tax(array('pa_color','red'))) {
    echo "<h2>Hello World</h2>";
    }
}
```

But it didn't work.

Can anyone take a minute to help me fix this code please?

Any help is greatly appreciated,
thank you

Comment: This is actually a pretty basic PHP question and hence offtopic here, but have a look at this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-151 You'll need something like `is_tax('pa_color','red')` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/#comment-806

Comment: hi @kraftner Thank you for your quick reply.

Can you give an example by editing the code above?
I really don't understand.

Comment: you've misunderstood the meaning of `&&`, it means `AND`, aka "if it is both A and B". What you meant is probably OR not AND, aka "if it is A or B" ( `||` ). This is a basic programming question rather than a WordPress question. Also be wary as WooCommerce questions are off topic here and not allowed. This is not a place to get help with the WooCommerce plugin or for help writing code for it

Answer (score 0):

`is_tax()` does not take its arguments as an array. Change:

```
if (is_tax('pa_size') && is_tax(array('pa_color','red')))
```

to

```
if (is_tax('pa_size') && is_tax('pa_color','red'))
```